# Why is JFrame layout not the one I set?

Tags: java, swing, layout, puzzle

If I set a layout on a `JFrame` with `setLayout` and then retrieve it with `getLayout` then I get a different `LayoutManager`. What is going on here??

```
public class Lay {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                java.awt.Container container =
                    new javax.swing.JFrame();
                    //new javax.swing.JPanel();
                java.awt.LayoutManager layout =
                    new java.awt.GridLayout();
                container.setLayout(layout);
                layout = container.getLayout();
                System.err.println(layout);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Gives

```
java.awt.BorderLayout[hgap=0,vgap=0]
```

but if I replace `JFrame` with `JPanel` I get

```
java.awt.GridLayout[hgap=0,vgap=0,rows=1,cols=0]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [Java API for `JFrame`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html):

> ```
> public void setLayout(LayoutManager manager)
> ```
>
> Sets the `LayoutManager`. Overridden to conditionally forward the call to the `contentPane`. Refer to [`RootPaneContainer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/RootPaneContainer.html) for more information.

And from the [`RootPaneContainer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/RootPaneContainer.html) page:

> This interface serves as a marker for Swing GUI builders that need to treat components like `JFrame`, that contain a single `JRootPane`, specially. For convenience `JFrame`, `JDialog`, `JWindow`, `JApplet` and `JInternalFrame`, by default, forward, by default, all calls to the `add`, `remove` and `setLayout` methods, to the `contentPane`. This means you can call:
>
> ```
> rootPaneContainer.add(component);
> ```
>
> instead of:
>
> ```
> rootPaneContainer.getContentPane().add(component);
> ```

A `JRootPane` is a common component that all the heavyweight components use to appear like a native OS window. It handles the menu bar, close/minimize/maximize buttons, etc. `JFrame` tries to hide the fact that `JRootPane` does the real work from you, but in this case it just made things more confusing.

Comment: For the rationale behind the getContentPane stuff, Hans Muller explains: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/hansmuller/archive/2005/11/jframeadd_conte.html